# Orchard CMS Custom Layout using KendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, orchardcms

Have anyone tried creating custom layout for Orchard's `query/projection` functionality? The default layout available when you install `Orchard` are `Grid` and `List`, I'm planning to add custom layout grid using `KendoUI` (Grid, Listview) while also taking advantage of the Orchards framework, the kendoui grid should be able to display content and non content types. Any idea on where to start? If you can direct me to a sample project implementing this that would be cool...

Comment: iirc, kendoui needs json as input, so you would need to return the projection data as json. Take a look at how the two types of projection views (grid and list I think) do it now then try and adapt that I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Layout Provider in your theme, which allows you to output the projection data however you wish.

Steve Taylor has a [tutorial on writing a custom Layout Provider](http://www.stevetaylor.me.uk/image-carousel-using-twitter-bootstrap-and-orchard-cms-projections) for creating a carousel using Projections, you could look at his examples to develop your own suiting your needs.